# Ambitious return trip from Germany to Australia

Tags: airports, germany, australia, connecting-flights

Long story short, I plan to leave my accomodation in Freiburg im Breisgau after 6 p.m. local time on Friday, February 15th. My goal is to get to Sydney or Melbourne by Sunday morning (i.e. before 12 p.m. local time), then catch another flight to Adelaide.

I am open to crazy travel ideas that may help me achieve this goal.

There is an Emirates flight to Melbourne departing Frankfurt at 8:30 p.m., and eventually arriving 6:30 a.m. However, it seems impossible to get from Freiburg to Frankfurt within the specified time range. I am open to a variety of alternative options.

Comment: Have you considered travelling through Zurich instead of Frankfurt?

Comment: Make sure you budget enough time for the international to domestic connection in Sydney. It's a non trivial connection and you terminals are pretty far apart.

Comment: There's a Lufthansa flight from Frankfurt at 21:55 that takes you to Melbourne via Singapore. Arrive Sunday 6:30. With that flight you can also go directly from Singapore to Adelaide.

Comment: Do you need to get to Sydney (i.e. you already have the Sydney-Adelaide flight booked, or you need to to something in Sydney before going to Adelaide), or do you just need to get to Adelaide?

Comment: Many flight search engines will let you narrow your search by departure and arrival time.

Comment: @NateEldredge the difficulty here is probably picking the departure airport and the way to get there, and take into account the combination of travel time from Freiburg to each airport and flight departure times from that airport. Google Maps doesn't combine the trip to the airport with the flight, and Rome2Rio does not allow selection of departure times, AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas, everyone. No particular reason for Sydney, I just need to get to Adelaide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work:

Train Freiburg to Zurich airport, 18:12-20:21

Fly Zurich to Singapore, 22:45-18:00 (Sat)

Fly Singapore to Sydney, 20:05-06:50 (Sun)

Fly Sydney to Adelaide, 10:25-12:00

Or you could go directly from Singapore to Adelaide and save yourself 3 hours.

Comment: This is a good option. Would 21:15 be too late to arrive at Zürich airport if I caught a later train?

Answer (score 2):

#### Another option, departing from Basel Euroairport:

- Bus from Freiburg to Basel Euroairport: 18:00 - 18:57

OR

- Train Freiburg to Basel SBB: 18:12 - 18:54
- Bus from Basel SBB to Basel Euroairport: 19:05 - 19:22 (there's one earlier, but you probably won't make it).

THEN

- Basel Euroairport - Munich: 20:30 - 21:30 (LH)
- Munich - Hong Kong: 22:30 - 16:40+1 (LH)
- Hong Kong - Adelaide: 00:15+2 - 11:40+2 (CX)

The check-in/bag drop deadline at Basel is 19:50.

#### Yet another one, leaving from Frankfurt:

- Train Freiburg - Mannheim: 18:57 - 20:24
- Train Mannheim - Frankfurt Airport: 20:36 - 21:06
- Frankfurt - Hong Kong: 22:15 - 16:15+1 (LH)
- Hong Kong - Adelaide: 00:15+2 - 11:40+2 (CX)

**This one is probably not doable if you have hold luggage, as the check-in/bag drop deadline is at 21:15.**

The best option is still probably the one [via Zurich](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/131163/30703).

Comment: For Lufthansa flights you can drop off the luggage at a special counter near the train station. Still, 9 minutes is probably too little even under these circumstances.